# Can we Connect two android Devices without Sockets?

Tags: java, android, sockets, communication

Is there any other way of Communication between Two Android Devices without Using Sockets Programmed in Java ? Does Java provide some other way to do this stuff ?

Comment: Like what?  Networking basics don't change.

Comment: Like text messaging, or IM, or something? Yup, no doubt. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Via a bluetooth.. [socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html), Phone calls, SMS, usind direct loudspeaker to microphone "connection" & some devices can also "communicate" via NFC, but beyond that, there is no other communication technology built into typical devices. So any practical communication uses a socket, at least under the hood.

Comment: @duffymo  Java provides RMI and .Net Provides Remoting Concepts but Android doesn't have these concepts. So I wanna to know if Android has Some Latest Techniques !

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326901/the-significance-of-java-rmi-please for some latest developments regarding RMI

Comment: There's of course the (obvious) option to let the communication happen trough a backend server. You can re-invent a wheel of your own or use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). And direct device-to-device communication of course has its own challenges as we are talking about mobile devices that might be far away from each other and might not even have a public IP address.

Comment: What do you think RMI is using underneath?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Bluetooth is also not allowed, you can still connect two Android devices together.

You can do this with [USB OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go). Some Android devices support this and Android has an official API that supports this.

You need an OTG Connector, a USB cable and **one** of those Android devices **must** support OTG.

API reference and examples:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/05/bright-idea-android-open-accessories.html

[Android USB host and hidden devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183792/android-usb-host-and-hidden-devices)